# How to return a message form shell script to Ansible playbook to Display as output

Tags: shell, ansible

I am running shell script via playbook

```
 - name: Get status of Filebeat
   shell: sh /path/get_status.sh "status"
   when: action == "status"
```

my shell script is get_status.sh

```
    SERVICE="filebeat"
    if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
    then
      echo "$SERVICE is running"
    else
      echo "$SERVICE is stopped"
```

I want this echo statement of shell script to be on ansible output, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your initial question you may just [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the [return value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html).

```
---
- hosts: test
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Verify service status
    shell:
      cmd: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test.sh"
      warn: false
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: false
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show result] *******
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg: RUNNING
```

- [Displaying output of a remote command with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20981211/6771046)

If your service is installed in your system in the same way like other services, a better approach might be to use Ansible build-ins.

- [How to check service exists in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69771608/)
- [Check if service exists with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328506/)
- [How to get service status by Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847824/)

If you are [running `filebeat` with systemd](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-with-systemd.html), you may use [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html)_module.

```
- name: Make sure service is started
  systemd:
    name: filebeat
    state: started
```

Comment: This is not installed as a service, I am just running a filebeat binary to start service and kill it to stop.
In the above solution how am I running my shell file?
I tried cmd: sh /path/get_status.sh "status", it gives output as "msg": "result.stdout"

Comment: @Priya, regarding your objection "_In the above solution how am I running my shell file?_", you may just call it within the command line. I am update the example accordingly. For debugging puprose you may also change the message to `msg: "{{ result }}"`.